# network push & pull data

Tags: networking

I' watching the system monitor.  I've got nothing opened, no browser or email client.  I see that i'm still receiving about 18 KB/s.  Is there any way to find out what program is asking for it or what site or IP it's coming from?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you enable `ufw`, the default firewall.

```
sudo ufw enable
```

Now enable logging:

```
sudo ufw logging high
```

Now you can check the system logs for details:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i ufw
```

You may see an entry like this:

> Apr  6 10:54:24 T440p kernel: [151434.303127] [UFW AUDIT] IN=
>   OUT=wlp3s0 SRC=192.168.0.120 DST=162.125.18.133 LEN=1086 TOS=0x00
>   PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=40870 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=54590 DPT=443 WINDOW=1136
>   RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0

Then you can check the identity:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install whois
whois 162.125.18.133
```

And the response is, in part:

```
OrgName:        Dropbox, Inc.
OrgId:          DROPB
Address:        333 Brannan Street
City:           San Francisco
StateProv:      CA
PostalCode:     94107
Country:        US
```

So that suggests that, even though no browser or email program is open, I have Dropbox installed and it is communicating any changes to my Dropbox folders.

Be careful, with logging set to high, large log files will build up fast. I recommend that, after you've made your checks, change the logging back to low or off:

```
sudo ufw logging off
```